# Static inner class in python

Tags: python, oop, static, inner-classes, static-classes

My code needs to have an inner class and I want to create the instance of this inner class without creating the instance of outer class.
**How to do so in python?** In java we can define the inner class to be static but I don't know how to make a inner class static in python. I know that for methods we can use `@staticmethod` decorator.

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Instance of outer class is created'

    class Inner:
        def __init__(self):
            print 'Instance of Inner class is created'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you need this?

Comment: Emil H: for example for everything? :D Nesting is widely used it gives you greater control over encapsulation and what interface/constants/helpers you provide for end-user while still keeping the "black box" code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The class Inner is defined during the definition of the class Outer and it exists in its class namespace afterwards. So just `Outer.Inner()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special. Just refer to it directly:

```
instance = Outer.Inner()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you looking for. You can just create it as class variable or as global (module) variable

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Instance of outer class is created'

    class Inner:
        def __init__(self):
            print 'Instance of Inner class is created'

    i = Inner() # as class varaible

i1 = Outer.Inner() # as module varaible
```